# Can custom format be defined via formula (without use of VBA)

Tags: excel

I need a custom format which would show a given number of decimal places. The number of the decimal places would be defined by a value of a cell. Can it be done without the use of VBA?

I created a formula that describes custom format with the desired number of decimal places (i.e. formula in cell B1 ="# ###"&","&SUBSTITUTE(10^A1;"1";""), where A1 is desired number of decimal places).

I was wondering if it is possible to "link" the output of the formula in cell B1 to the custom formatting applied to cell C1 so it would change every time I change cell A1. Can this be done without VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, yes.

```
=If

=Text
```

Those two formulas together should accomplish what you want for number formatting.

For cell highlights, you want to look into conditional formatting. Conditional formatting would also work for your first issue

Comment: This is my 1st question here, so I guess I could be more precise. To be more specific - let's say C1 = 12 123,1234. I would like the format of the cell to be dependent on cell A1. So if A1 = 1, then C1 still equals 12 123,1234, but displayed amount is 12 123,1. But, actually, since excel has 15 decimal digit precision limit, I can simply add a limited number of conditions (I didn't want to use them first, forgot that there is precision limit). So CF will help indeed. Thx a lot.

Comment: No problem :). Generally, pure-excel questions go on Superuser, while questions relating to VBA go on Stack Overflow